# RNN model not learning anything

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am practicing with RNN. I randomly create 5 integers. If the first integer is an odd number, the y value is 1, otherwise y is 0 (So, only the first x counts). Problem is, when I run this model, it does not 'learn': val_loss and val_accuracy does not change over epochs. What would be the cause?

```
from keras.layers import SimpleRNN, LSTM, GRU, Dropout, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np

data_len = 300
x = []
y = []
for i in range(data_len):
    a = np.random.randint(1,10,5)
    if a[0] % 2 == 0:
        y.append('0')
    else:
        y.append('1')

    a = a.reshape(5, 1)
    x.append(a)
    print(x)

X = np.array(x)
Y = np.array(y)   

model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(units=24, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=[5,1])) 
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(GRU(units=12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(X[:210], Y[:210], epochs=20, validation_split=0.2)
```

**Epoch 1/20**
168/168 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.4345 - accuracy: 0.5655 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
...

**Epoch 20/20**
168/168 [==============================] - 0s 315us/step - loss: 0.4345 - accuracy: 0.5655 - val_loss: 0.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.5000

Comment: I found a good explanation on this issue: https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-choose-last-layer-activation-and-loss-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using *softmax activation* with 1 neuron, which always returns **[1]**. Use *sigmoid activation* with 1 neuron for binary classification, and *softmax* for multiple neurons for multiclass classification

Comment: That solved the issue with val_loss. Thank you. Still val_accuracy stays the same over epochs at 0.5238. Why would it be not learning although it is at a low level?

Comment: Maybe because your data is random? There's nothing to learn, there's no structure

Answer (score 0):

Change data_len to a higher number like 30000 and it will be able to learn. Right now the amount of data is very small. and ofcourse, you'll need to change the activation (to sigomid) -- as suggested by Yoskutik